# No Responsive for any screen size

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I make two page and use the expanded widgte..but not responsive in small screen...
when use very small font in my app will ok...(im use auto size text but not ok)
please watch my code and help me for responsive app
also i use mediaquery but not ok

thank you

[image]

```
             const BottomContainerHeight = 80.0;

               class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
            const InputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

                   @override
                 _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
               }

         enum Gender {
              male,
             female,
             }

              class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
          late Gender selectedGender = Gender.female;
            int height = 180;
         int weight = 70;
          int age = 24;

                 @override
                 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                 Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
                 Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
                 return Scaffold(
                   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
             appBar: AppBar(
             title: const Text(
                  " bmiمحاسبه ",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                    ),
                   flexibleSpace: Container(
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                const Color(0xFF3366FF),
                const Color(0xFF00CCFF),
              ],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
              stops: [0.0, 1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
        ),
      ),
       centerTitle: true,
      elevation: 3.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.redAccent,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
    ),
    body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.5,
                        child: ReusableCard(
                          colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                              ? activeCardColoursFemale
                              : inactiveCardColoursFemale,
                          cardChild: IconContent(
                            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.2,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.5,
                            svgPicture: 'assets/2.svg',
                            label: 'خانم',
                          ),
                          onPress: () {
                            selectedGender = Gender.female;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.9,
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.5,
                        child: ReusableCard(
                          colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                              ? activeCardColoursMale
                              : inactiveCardColoursMale,
                          cardChild: IconContent(
                            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.2,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth * 99,
                            svgPicture: 'assets/3.svg',
                            label: 'آقا',
                          ),
                          onPress: () {
                            selectedGender = Gender.male;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: ReusableCard(
                onPress: () {},
                colour: [Color(0xff5f72bd), Color(0xff9b23ea)],
                //colour: Color(0xFF65E655),
                cardChild: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      ':میزان قد شما',
                      style: labelTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'سانتیمتر',
                          style: labelTextStyle,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          height.toString(),
                          style: numTextStyle,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SliderTheme(
                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                          inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white,
                          activeTrackColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                          thumbColor: Colors.amber,
                          overlayColor: Color(0x1fFFF176),
                          thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                              enabledThumbRadius: 15.0)
                          //shape ra bozorgtr mikonad...
                          ,
                          overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(
                              overlayRadius: 30.0) //saye dor shape miandzad
                          ),
                      child: Slider(
                        value: height.toDouble(),
                        min: 120.0,
                        max: 220.0,
                        onChanged: (double newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            height = newValue.round();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ReusableCard(
                        onPress: () {},
                        colour: [Colors.teal, Colors.tealAccent],
                        //colour: Color(0xFF65E655),
                        cardChild: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'وزن',
                              style: labelTextStyle,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              weight.toString(),
                              style: numTextStyle,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                RoundIconButton(
                                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        weight--;
                                      });
                                    }),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                ),
                                RoundIconButton(
                                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        weight++;
                                      });
                                    }),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ReusableCard(
                        onPress: () {},
                        colour: [Color(0xfff9d423), Color(0xfff83600)],
                        //colour: Color(0xFF65E655),
                        cardChild: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'سن',
                              style: labelTextStyle,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              age.toString(),
                              style: numTextStyle,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                RoundIconButton(
                                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        age--;
                                      });
                                    }),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                ),
                                RoundIconButton(
                                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        age++;
                                      });
                                    }),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            BottomBotton(
              onTap: () {
                CalculatorBrain calc =
                    CalculatorBrain(height: height, weight: weight);
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ResultPage(
                              bmiResult: calc.calculateBmi(),
                              resultText: calc.getResult(),
                              feedBack: calc.getFeedBack(),
                            )));
              },
              bottonTitle: 'محاسبه',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }));
  }
 }
```

and please watch result page like my home screen page
thank you for help me

[image]

```
                      class ResultPage extends StatelessWidget {
                                  ResultPage({required this.bmiResult,
             required this.resultText,
                          required this.feedBack});

                          final String bmiResult;
                   final String resultText;
                                  final String feedBack;

                                    @override
                            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                                         return Scaffold(
                                            appBar: AppBar(
                                 backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                               flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  const Color(0xFF3366FF),
                  const Color(0xFF00CCFF),
                ],
                begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp)),
      ),
      title: Text(
        ' bmiمحاسبه   ',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'assets/fonts/iraniansans', color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
    body: SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .height,
      width: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .width,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(

              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Text(
                'نتیجه تست شما',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'assets/font/iraniansans',
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topRight,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          colors: [Color(0xfffff1eb), Color(0xfface0f9)],
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                        Image.asset(
                        'assets/shakhes.png',
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * 99,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.4,
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.9,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [Text(
                            resultText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'assets/font/iraniansans',
                                fontSize: 30.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.green),
                          ),
                            Text(
                              bmiResult,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'assets/font/iraniansans',
                                  fontSize: 30.0,
                                  color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              feedBack,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'assets/font/iraniansans',
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              maxLines: 3,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],))
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: BottomBotton(
                bottonTitle: 'محاسبه دوباره',
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the problem in your code is not with `width` and `height`, but with font size because font size differs from screen to screen. I would strongly recommend you to use [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) package to create responsive flutter apps. What this plugin does is that it define the size into the percent of your screen. For instance:

```
Container(
  height: 20.0.h,    //20% of the screen height
  width: 20.0.w,     //20% of the screen width
)
```

As far as font goes, you can define the size of the fonts by using `sp` keyword. Like this:

```
Text(
  "Aloysius",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 15.0.sp
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@media` query in `fontSize` of your texts too and it will be ok

Like this:

```
Text('نتیجه تست شما',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'assets/font/iraniansans',
            fontSize: 35.0, // it is wrong
            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/15, // true
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.red),
),
```

Also you need to use `@media` query in size of your pictures.